# How do I copy "What's new in this version" metadata from my previous release in iTunesConnect while releasing a new app update?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm submitting an app update for review to iTunes. I would like to copy **"What's new in this version"** from my previous release for English(UK), French and Spanish but English(US). How can I do this?

I know this facility is available for Android apps.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is builtin functionality in the Play Store, iTunesConnect does not support that.

You can use [fastlate](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/appstore-deployment/) to achieve that. It basically means that you need to save the metadata in files and fastlane will upload it for you to iTunesConenct. The good part is that you can also commit those files to a repo and have versioning for the metadata.